# Co ordinate geometry perpendicular distance between two points

Tags: geometry

If perpendicular distance from given point(lying on that line) to other point is given then How do I find Co ordinates of other point?

Answer (score 1):

Say 2 points $P(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q(x_2,y_2)$ lie on $y=mx+c$.

You have 2 equations: $$(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2=d^2$$ $$y_2=mx_2+c$$
You know the values of $x_1,y_1,m,c$ and $d$. Find $x_2$ and $y_2$.

Comment: Do you actually mean $(x_2-x_1)^2 +(y_2 -y_1)^2=d^2 $ ?

Comment: @Nameless Thanks. It was a typo error.